# Spring Integration Java DSL: Remote filter is not applied on handle method

Tags: java, filter, spring-integration, dsl, handle

I want to read specific files from a SFTP server and get only compressed files only once.
I encounter a problem when handling message because the defined filter on the remote server seems to not be applied in handle method.

Dependencies:

- SpringBoot: 2.2.1
- spring-integration: 5.2.1
- spring-integration-jdbc: 5.2.1
- spring-integration-sftp: 5.2.1

```
    public IntegrationFlow buildSftpInboundIntegrationFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(
                        Sftp
                        .inboundStreamingAdapter(buildSftpRemoteFileTemplate())
                        .remoteDirectory(getRemoteDirectoryPath())
                        .filter(buildRemoteFileFilter())
                        .remoteFileSeparator(
                                Optional
                                .ofNullable(getRemoteFileSeparator())
                                .orElse(DEFAULT_REMOTE_PATH_SEPARATOR))
                        .maxFetchSize(
                                Optional.ofNullable(getMaxFetchSize()).orElse(DEFAULT_MAX_FETCH_SIZE)),
                        sourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec -> sourcePollingChannelAdapterSpec
                        .id(getSftpInboundStreamingAdapterIdentifier())
                        .autoStartup(true)
                        .poller(buildPollerSpec()))
                .handle(handleMessage())
                .get();
    }

    /**
     * Allows to build a regex to filter files.
     *
     * @return a regex as a {@link String}.
     */
    private String buildRegexFileFilter() {
        return String.format(".*\\.%s", getFileExtensionToFilter());
    }

    /**
     * Allows to build an instance of {@link SftpRemoteFileTemplate}.
     *
     * @return an instance of {@link SftpRemoteFileTemplate}.
     */
    private SftpRemoteFileTemplate buildSftpRemoteFileTemplate() {
        final SftpRemoteFileTemplate sftpRemoteFileTemplate = new SftpRemoteFileTemplate(getSftpSessionFactory());
        sftpRemoteFileTemplate.setAutoCreateDirectory(true);

        return sftpRemoteFileTemplate;
    }

    /**
     * Allows to build the filters to apply to the remote files.
     *
     * @return an instance of {@link CompositeFileListFilter}.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    private CompositeFileListFilter<LsEntry> buildRemoteFileFilter() {
        return new ChainFileListFilter<LsEntry>() // NOSONAR
                .addFilters(
                        new SftpRegexPatternFileListFilter(buildRegexFileFilter()),
                        getSftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter());
    }

    /**
     * Allows to build the poller specifications.
     *
     * @return an instance of {@link PollerSpec}.
     */
    private PollerSpec buildPollerSpec() {
        return Pollers
                .fixedDelay(
                       Optional.ofNullable(getPollerDelayInSeconds()).orElse(DEFAULT_POLLER_DELAY_IN_SECONDS),
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .transactional()
                .transactionSynchronizationFactory(getTransactionSynchronizationFactory());
    }
...
```

Do you have any ideas to suggest to me ?
why in the handle method I receive files which should be excluded by the remote filter ?
It is a bug ? How get filtered messages ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug in the modules spring-integration and spring-integration-sftp in version 5.2.1.
It works by upgrading these dependencies in version 5.2.2. (December 6, 2019)